# How can I hover the color of my text in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I have build a popup button using Flutter but I'm not finding a way to change the text color when I put my cursor over it without clicking it. I want that the title of the popupbutton to change in pink. Does anyone knows how can I do this? Below you can find my code sample

```
PopupMenuButton(
                    tooltip: '',
                    child: Text(
                      'Hello',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 24,
                        fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                      ),
                    ),
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => <PopupMenuEntry>[]),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First define a variable for each `PopupMenuButton` like this:

```
bool firstIshovering = false;
bool secondIshovering = false;
```

then wrap your `PopupMenuButton` with `MouseRegion` widget if you want the all `PopupMenuButton` get hover:

```
MouseRegion(
            onEnter: (details) => setState(() => firstIshovering = true),
            onExit: (details) => setState(() {
              firstIshovering = false;
            }),
            child: PopupMenuButton(
                tooltip: '',
                child: Text(
                  'Hello',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: firstIshovering ? Colors.red : Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 24,
                    fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                  ),
                ),
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => <PopupMenuEntry>[]),
          ),

 MouseRegion(
            onEnter: (details) => setState(() => secondIshovering = true),
            onExit: (details) => setState(() {
              secondIshovering = false;
            }),
            child: PopupMenuButton(
                tooltip: '',
                child: Text(
                  'Hello',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: secondIshovering ? Colors.red : Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 24,
                    fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                  ),
                ),
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => <PopupMenuEntry>[]),
          ),
```

if you want just `child text` get hover use this:

```
PopupMenuButton(
              tooltip: '',
              child: MouseRegion(
                onEnter: (details) => setState(() => ishovering = true),
                onExit: (details) => setState(() {
                  ishovering = false;
                }),
                child: Text(
                  'Hello',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: ishovering ? Colors.red : Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 24,
                    fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => <PopupMenuEntry>[]),
```

Comment: I don't understand one thing. When I try it to my other Popupmenubuttons it hovers color for all of them at the same time. I want that to happen for each one only when i put cursor over one of them. @eamirho3ein

Comment: oo you have more than one ?

Comment: yes please @eamirho3ein

Comment: I tried it but still the same. Can you make an example how can i use it @eamirho3ein

Answer (score 0):

you can use **mouseRegion** class of **flutter**.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MouseRegion-class.html

```
MouseRegion(
        onHover: _updateColor,
        child: Container()
        );
```